# How to sharex and sharey axis in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to share the x-axis and y-axis of my sumplots, I've tried using the sharey and sharex several different ways but haven't gotten the correct result.

```
ax0 = plt.subplot(4,1,1)
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(4,1,i+1,sharex = ax0)
    plt.plot(wavelength[i],flux)
    plt.xlim([-1000,1000])
    plt.ylim([0,1.5])
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you explain what the correct result should be? This isn't very much to go off of.

Comment: Right now I have 4 plots stacked that each have the same x axis. I just want the bottom plot to show the axis

Comment: Also I have 4 identical y axes that I want to be shared

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, want to have four stacked plots, sharing the x-axis and the y-axis.  This you can do with [plt.subplots](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) and the keywords `sharex=True` and `sharey=True`.  See example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axlist = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axlist:
    ax.plot(np.random.random(100))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it made the stack for 4 identical plots. Is there a way to make it for 4 different arrays? (wavelength[i])

Comment: Ofcourse you can plot whatever you like inside the for-loop, but remember that if you want to share the axes, they will indeed be shared (i.e. having the same x/y limits and the same "view").  If you want to plot different data, with completely different values...you do NOT want to share the axes...